# Grouping & Output of Categories & Subcategories

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I'm working on a fairly basic menu system whereby all categories are held in a single table, with subcategories flagged in a field 'issubcategoryof'.  At the output level, categories that have subcategories do not have a value for the 'link' field (clicking on the category name triggers a view of the subcategories), but all subcategories have a link value (and of course, categories without a subcategory do have a link value).  For the avoidance of doubt, subcategories only go 1 level (so category > subcategory).

The query and output works in the sense it is correctly showing the category and subcategory names as it should, however 'link' values are not being passed for subcategories for some reason. By that I mean the `#link#` alongside `#subcatheader#` is empty when output, but there should be a value.

Here's the query and the output I currently have;

```
<cfquery name="getnav">
SELECT p.navID AS PrimaryID, p.catheader, p.navsort, p.link, c.navID AS SubCategoryID, c.subcatheader, c.link
FROM  sitenav p 
LEFT JOIN sitenav c ON p.navID = c.IsSubcatOf 
WHERE  p.isSubcatOf = 0
ORDER BY p.navsort ASC
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="getnav" group="catheader">
    <div class="sidebar-menu">
       <cfif link NEQ ''>
          <a href="#link#">#catheader#</a>
       <cfelse>
          #catheader#
       </cfif>
       <div class="expand"></div>
    </div>
    <cfif link EQ ''> 
        <div class="sub-menu">
        <ul>
            <cfoutput>
               <li><a href="#link#">#subcatheader#</a></li>
            </cfoutput>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

I've been staring at this for a while and it seems as though I'm missing something really obvious, but it alludes me at the moment!  Any pointers most welcome!

Comment: What do you mean the link values are not being passed? Without ordering by `catheader` this should not be working at all.

Comment: Essentially, the #link# alongside #subcatheader# is empty when output - but there should be a value.

Comment: Rather than us guessing, it would help to see a dump of the raw query data, ie getnav.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do this in a comment, but I don't have enough rep. points.  Anyway, you have two "link" fields, one each for p and c.  Perhaps you need to give them different names?

Comment: Do not know if it is the issue, but that is a good observation :) +1

Comment: That was it!  I altered the query to 'c.link AS sublink' and it works perfectly now.  Thanks!

Comment: My vote put your reputation over 100.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: Dan, If you're ever in Hawaii!